# Updating numeric variable but getting NaN

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to update the position of a object in `canvas` but when I try to add `dt` to the position I get only `NaN`.If I try a console log I get `NaN` and some random numbers.
Even if I try with a simple variable initialized with `0` I get the same `NaN` stuff

```
function update(dt) {
    player.pos[0] += dt;
    player.pos[1] += dt;
    gameTime += dt;
    console.log(gameTime + " " + dt);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NHmDa/)

Comment: What are the contents of the variables that you are trying to add `dt` to, which variable are you specifically having a problem with or is it all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `lastTime` variable; You are using it in a arithmetic operation without initializing it first.

Try this
http://jsfiddle.net/NHmDa/1/

Comment: there is a link in the question

Comment: SO I can't add something to Nan?

Comment: Well as the name suggests, Nan is not a number. It is a special primitive type in JavaScript which cannot participate in arithmetic operations. It will evaluate always to NaN. It is a good practice to always initialize your variables.

Comment: @tHIScOdeIsBeNaNaS There's a `isNaN()` function to check if a number is a real if you need.

Answer (score 1):

At very fisrt, you are declaring the variable `var lastTime;`  without assging any default value, I think it should be declare something like this.

```
var lastTime = 0;
```

The problem is in this line when you  do not assign any numeric value to `lastTime`

```
var dt = (now - lastTime) / 1000.0;
```

Comment: Where did you get that variable from?

Comment: earlier he provided the jsfiddle but now he deleted that link.